# Android Access inbox

Tags: android, inbox

I want to show few sms available in inbox in my application. And how to identify or to distinguish to sms from others? Is there any message ID or something to identify sms?

Comment: To identify what? Who send it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a store a reference to individual SMS messages?
If so you could do this by storing the unique content provider address of each SMS. E.g.

```
content://sms/inbox/1
```